# executable in PATH not found

Tags: bash, mongodb, path

I have an executable located in PATH, but it cannot be found when I type the command.

The result from `$PATH` is: 
    -bash: /Users/aridyckovsky/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin:/Users/aridyckovsky/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin:/Users/aridyckovsky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/aridyckovsky/.rvm/bin: No such file or directory`

Specifically, I am trying to execute `mongod` in /usr/local/bin, but the result is `-bash: mongod: command not found`. I can run other executables in the same location, however. Any ideas?

Comment: so what does `ls -l /usr/local/bin/mongod`  say ?

Comment: do a 'ls -l  full path to your file and post it here.

Comment: the result is: `lrwxr-xr-x  1 aridyckovsky  admin  34 Nov 11 13:43 /usr/local/bin/mongod -> ../Cellar/mongodb/2.4.8/bin/mongod`

Comment: @user3192285 Just because the symlink exists doesn't mean the actual script exists (and you will get the same error if the symlink is broken). Can you also do `ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.8/bin/mongod`

Comment: Looks like there is not existing script ls: `/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.8/bin/mongod: No such file or directory`

Comment: I have figured out the fix. Thanks to @BroSlow, I saw that there was no link to mongod, even though mongodb was installed. So, I used `brew link --overwrite mongodb` to delete the bad symlinks and create the needed link.

Answer (score 2):

You'll get that error when you try to execute `$PATH` as a command.

```
$ $PATH
bash: /home/glennj/bin:...:/opt/tcl/8.6/bin: No such file or directory
```

In bash, use the `type` builtin to find things:

```
$ type mongod
mongod is /usr/bin/mongod
```

Use `type -a` to also show aliases and functions

```
$ type -a ls
ls is aliased to `ls -F'
ls is /bin/ls
$ type -a git
git is a function
git () 
{ 
    case "$1" in 
        push | pull)
            if (( $# == 1 )); then
                local branch=$(git_current_branch);
                if [[ -n $branch ]]; then
                    set -- $1 origin "$branch";
                    echo git "$@";
                else
                    echo "You're not in a git-managed directory" 1>&2;
                    return;
                fi;
            fi
        ;;
    esac;
    command git "$@"
}
git is /usr/bin/git
```

Comment: +1 Not so sure it answers the question, but like the type `hint`. Knew `type` > `which` for bash, but didn't know about the `a` flag. Definitely overriding which='type -a' on my bash.